# bluetooth data recieved from arduino gets divided into chunks in python

Tags: python, arduino, bluetooth, pyserial

I was trying to send IMU data from MPU6050 from arduino pro micro to my pc using HC-05, and I wrote a small program in python to recieve it, but the data gets printed in different lines or gets divided into chunks.

Here is the Arduino code, I am using the Serial1 line to send data through HC-05.

```
Serial1.print(ypr[0]*180/M_PI);
Serial1.print(",");
Serial1.print(ypr[1]*180/M_PI);
Serial1.print(",");
Serial1.println(ypr[2]*180/M_PI);
```

And here is the code for reception, in python:

```py
import bluetooth 
import serial
target_name = "HC-05"
target_address = None
        
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
        
for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
    if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name(bdaddr):
        target_address = bdaddr
        break
    if target_address is not None:
        print ("found target bluetooth device with address ", target_address)
    else:
        print ("could not find target bluetooth device nearby")

port = 1
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
size = 512
sock.connect((target_address, port))
print("CONNECTED")

    while True:
        data = sock.recv(size)
        data=data.decode('ascii')
        # data=data.strip()
        # imu=data.split(',')
        print(data)
```

The Data is getting printed like this in python:
[image: python printing data in chunks and unordered]

But I want it to be like this, as in Serial Monitor of arduino
[image: yaw pitch and roll values in order]

Comment: Your request is impossible. BT sends data in packets. Serial port sends data in stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest sending the values as bytes. It looks like you will need two bytes per x, y, and z value of the imu. You can get the value from the imu into an integer by multiplying by a value to remove the decimal places. e.g 12.34 * 100 is 1234.

At the other end of the Bluetooth link you can unpack the bytes and divide by the same number to get the original value back.

Example Arduino code:

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial hc06(3,2);

struct imu
{
  int16_t x;
  int16_t y;
  int16_t z;
};

imu state;

void setup(){
  //Initialize Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Initialize Bluetooth Serial Port
  hc06.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("setup done...");
  state.x = 12.34 * 100;
  state.y = 37.00 * 100;
  state.z = -10.99 * 100;
}

void loop(){
  // Write data from HC06 to Serial Monitor
    byte buf[6];
    buf[0] = state.x & 255;
    buf[1] = (state.x >> 8) & 255;
    buf[2] = state.y & 255;
    buf[3] = (state.y >> 8) & 255;
    buf[4] = state.z & 255;
    buf[5] = (state.z >> 8) & 255;
    hc06.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
    delay(2000);
}
```

And example Python code:

```py
"""
A simple Python script to receive bytes over Bluetooth using
Python sockets (with Python 3.3 or above).
"""

import socket
import struct

serverMACAddress = '00:00:12:06:53:92'
port = 1
with socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM) as s:
    s.connect((serverMACAddress, port))
    data = b''
    while True:
        while len(data) < 6:
            data += s.recv(1)
        x, y, z = struct.unpack('<hhh', data[:6])
        print(f"raw data={data} : x={x/100}, y={y/100}, z={z/100}")
        data = data[6:]
```

Which gave the output:

```
raw data=b'\xd2\x04t\x0e\xb5\xfb' : x=12.34, y=37.0, z=-10.99
raw data=b'\xd2\x04t\x0e\xb5\xfb' : x=12.34, y=37.0, z=-10.99
```

Comment: thanks for your help sir , but the python program stop after printing few values and shows this error     x, y, z = struct.unpack('<hhh', data)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 6 bytes

Comment: I am assuming that it has got too many bytes. Maybe print out `data` before the unpack to help with debug. Anyways, I've done an update to hopefully make it more robust. Hope that does the trick.

Comment: what if the values are of 3 digit (before decimal point) , will that be an issue ??

Comment: An `int16` will go from negative 32768 through positive 32767. If you have values out of that range then you will need to go to `in32` which is negative 2,147,483,648 through positive 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 0):

```
Serial1.print(ypr[0]*180/M_PI,",",ypr[1]*180/M_PI,",",ypr[2]*180/M_PI)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post

Comment: its showing this error

Comment: exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::print(double, const char [2], double, const char [2], double)'